# Как div может пропадать со страницы HTML после посещения ссылки?

Tags: css, веб-программирование, html5, вёрстка

Как сделать так, чтобы `<div>` пропадал со страницы HTML после посещения ссылки?
То что `display: none;` это понятно, а какой должна быть полная конструкция в CSS?

Пример:

```
<div class="чтобы пропал">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: [селекторов такого типа пока нету](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/5812238), так что видимо придётся javascript использовать

Comment: @Daria Shvakh Если вам ответ подошел, примите его. В сообществе так принято.

Comment: Как по мне, иных вариантов как этот, больше нет без JS.

Comment: Vlad Spirin, добрый день. Влад, спасибо за рекомендацию), а как "Принять" в интерфейсе - не видно кнопки. И если в дальнейшем что то я сделаю (или не сделаю) не так, и вы будете этому свидетель прошу - наставить и научить. Спасибо!

Comment: Я  бы с проголосовал за закрытие вопроса, но на кнопку ЗАКРЫТЬ я еще не нажал. `Daria Shvakh`,  что-бы получить ответ,  опиши вопрос  более продробно...  Я просто хочу понять, что именно ты хочешь и для чего...  Уверен, это интересно не только мне

Comment: Влад, да собственно все казалось - просто. На главной странице есть блок-ссылка (position:absolute), который перенаправляет посетителя на эту-же главную но с другим bg, и вот на этом новом эскизе этот блок - не уместен. Делать вторую копию страницы и направлять на неё - не решение, страница должна остаться та-же. Вот.

Comment: Влад, или вы что другое имели ввиду? Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем для смены бэкграунда перезагружать страницу?

Comment: @DariaShvakh Вам нужно отредактировать вопрос, возможно вы пытаетесь левой ногой почесать правое ухо. Опишите точнее конечную цель.

Comment: при нажатии на блок-ссылку отрабатывает JS который обеспечивает определённый визуальный эффект, в результате шапка - остаётся, футер - остаётся, а вот bg main - меняется. Ну дизайн такой. И вообщем всё - гуд, только блок-ссылка - "Пропади ты пропадом"(с) все портит(

Comment: Андрей, а скажите как принято на ресурсе - редактировать. 1) Как это я делаю сейчас в комментариях.или 2) Править сам вопрос который уже - опубликован? Спасибо. Я первый день на сайте.

Comment: На мой взгляд лучше править вопрос, добваляя новые сведения в конце, с префиксом `UPD#1:`

Comment: Андрей: т.е. 1) редактировать само тело опубликованного вопроса с символом UPD#1:(кстати, что значит и откуда?), или 2) Добавлять новый комментарий который будет начинаться UPD#1. В конце - чего?

Comment: @DariaShvakh https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Извините, только увидел что вы писали. Если хотите, чтоб определенный человек увидел ваше сообщение, ставьте перед его именем @

Comment: @DariaShvakh Вообще в целом взгляните на справку, там все до нас написано, что и как: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все когда-либо посещённые ссылки (которые окрашиваются по умолчанию в фиолетовый) подпадают под CSS-селектор `:visited`.

```css
.visit_once:visited {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<a class="visit_once" href="//example.com/">Если вы видите эту ссылку, значит вы не посещали её</a>
```

Важное замечание: вы не сможете полноценно скрыть посещённую ссылку через `display: none`, так как возможности селектора `visited` сильно ограничены в целях безопасности. Подробнее об этом можно почитать в статье «[Privacy-related changes coming to CSS :visited](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)» блога «Mozilla Hacks».

Comment: Для `.visit_once:visited` вместо `white`, лучше дать `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Но вопрос в том, чтобы `div` пропал, а не ссылка. Можно конечно `a:visited + div`, но для этого нужно поменять html.

Comment: Андрей, а что вы имеете ввиду ....a:visited + div

Comment: @DariaShvakh, `<div>`, следующий сразу же за посещённой `<a>`. Но у вас эти теги вложены, а не следуют друг за другом, поэтому данный селектор пока неприменим.

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```css
#disappear:target {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="disappear">
  <a href="#disappear">to disappear</a>
</div>
```

Comment: **Это совсем не то.** Ваш пример подразумевает, что после посещения ссылки кто-то должен дописать к её URL `#disappear`, чтобы сработал псевдокласс `:target`.

Comment: Это сам браузер дописывает из-за href="#disappear", а не кто-то.

Comment: Из-за необходимости дописывания блок снова появится при следующей загрузке страницы по обычному (каноническому) адресу.

Comment: Не вижу не соответствия вопросу.

Comment: <div id="disappear">
  <a href="http:yandex.ru">to disappear</a>
</div>, а как добавить еще один href = "#disappear", для "браузера"? Спасибо.

Comment: @DariaShakh Не понял вопроса.

Comment: Андрей, ну в вашем примере href в сторону #disappear, вы говорите что бы конструкция сработала браузер и должен дописать в урле #disappear, а если в реальном проекте href на страницу яндекс (или другую), то href уже будет не #disappear, а как тогда браузер допишет #disappear. Простите мой уровень - "табуретка для юзера". Спасибо.

Comment: Андрей как бы выглядел ваш РАБОЧИЙ пример если бы href ="https:yandex.ru"? Спасибо.

Comment: А, ну нет. #disappear допишется автоматически только при переходе по ссылке page.html#disappear. Если просто перейдете по ссылке page.html блок будет показан. При переходе на yandex вы не можете скрывать на нем никакие блоки. Это невозможно.

Comment: т.е///////////.#disappear:target {
  display: none;
}//////////////<div id="disappear">
  <a href="https:yandex.ru">to disappear</a>
</div>///////////тоже - сработает?

Comment: нет. тут был ответ @Arhad . решение на основе `:visited`, такой вариант должен вам помочь. странно что@Arhad удалил его.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, мой вариант скрывал не родительский блок, а саму ссылку. Вообще, исходная задача заключается в применении стиля при соблюдении условия у дочернего элемента, — этакий селектор `<`. Но такого селектора пока не существует, а потому моё решение не удастся быстро подправить.

Comment: Но на всякий случай восстановил ответ. // cc: @DariaShvakh

Comment: @Arhad надо же, не знал об ограничениях `:visited`